# Angularfire delete object from lookup list

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

(I'm very new to Angular and fairly new to coding so please forgive me if my question appears to be not so bright.)

I have projects and tasks as lists. I can add tasks into the projects and iterate them in a table within the project component (by using a denormalized lookup table). But I couldn't figure out how can I remove them from projects with the button that iterates in each row in the projectTasks table.

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/BSAYL6PfLLCQ7xXWIo2N?p=info

Project interface:

```
export interface Project {
$key: string;
name: string;
projectTasks: {
    [key: string]: {
        name: string;
        assignedTo?: string;
        dueDate?: String;
        estTime?: String;
    }
};}
```

Task Interface:

```
export interface Task {
$key: string;
name: string;
assignedTo?: string;
dueDate?: string;
estTime?: string; }
```

Add Task Function:

```
    //(selectedTask: Task, projectTasks = [];)
    addTask() {
    this.project.projectTasks[this.selectedTask.$key] = {
        name: this.selectedTask.name,
        assignedTo: this.selectedTask.assignedTo ? this.selectedTask.assignedTo : 'N/A',
        dueDate: this.selectedTask.dueDate ? this.selectedTask.dueDate : 'N/A' ,
        estTime: this.selectedTask.estTime ? this.selectedTask.estTime : 'N/A' ,
    };
    this.setProjectTasks();
```

Set Project Tasks Function:

```
    setProjectTasks() {
    if (this.project.projectTasks == null) {
        this.project.projectTasks = {};
    }
    this.projectTasks = Object.keys(this.project.projectTasks)
        .map(key => this.project.projectTasks[key]);
}
```

Remove Task Function: (removes the entire task node)

```
    removeTask(task) {
    this.taskService.removeTask(task)
    .then(_ => this.router.navigate([`ww/task-list`]) );
}
```

Task Service Remove Task:

```
    removeTask(task) {
    return this
        .tasks$
        .remove(task.$key)
        .then(_ => alert('Task Successfully Deleted'))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

I can iterate assigned tasks in a dropdown as shown and I need to find a logic to update addedTask with null value using the Remove button without having to remove the actual task node.

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="remove-row">Remove Tasks From Project</label>
<md-select placeholder="Select a Task" [(ngModel)]="selectedTask">
<md-option *ngFor="let projectTask of projectTasks" [value]="projectTask"> 
{{projectTask.name}} </md-option>
</md-select>
 <button class="btn btn-primary"
 (click)="removeProjectTask(projectTask)">Remove From Project</button>
```

Comment: `removeProjectTask(taskName: string) {const taskKey = Object.keys(this.project.projectTasks).find(key => {return this.project.projectTasks[key].name === this.selectedTask.name ;});`

        `delete this.project.projectTasks[taskKey];this.setProjectTasks();}` 

Is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following solution has worked for removing the object from the lookup table.

```
removeProjectTask(taskName: string) {
const taskKey = Object.keys(this.project.projectTasks)
  .find(key => {return this.project.projectTasks[key]
    .name === this.selectedTask.name ;}); 
delete this.project.projectTasks[taskKey];
this.setProjectTasks();
}
```